# Windows Explorer, MOV icon thumbnails are different on different drives

Tags: windows-explorer

I use my computer mostly for digital media production. When I'm looking for a video file, almost all of the major file formats show a frame of the video as the icon thumbnail and in the preview pane of Windows Explorer. movs are the most annoying exception because I export almost all of my work to ProRes movs. Instead of the first frame, I get the icon for the default app associated w/ mov playback. I found instructions to fix this, by unchecking "Display file icon as thumbnail" in the options for Windows Explorer, and that worked for files stored on my C: drive. But I store all of my media assets on a separate HDD and MOV icons are still showing as the app logo AFTER I followed the same steps as my C: drive. Does anybody know why this would be and, hopefully, how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot answer your question but I can give you a little insight.  Thumbnails are rendered by shell extensions that integrated into  the windows explorer.  MOV files have nothing to do with Microsoft and require Apple Quicktime to render them.  They are rendered by an Apple plugin that comes with the quicktime codec.  The Apple code isn't doing it's job and appears to be hard-coded to the c: drive (no big surprise).  You aren't the [first person](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mov-thumbnails-dont-show/8c9a8cd2-cef8-420d-ba2f-08626a4eda32?page=2) to have this problem.

Comment: I myself would suggest NOT rendering your video to a proprietary format like MOV OR move to a mac.  There is no advantage to using Apple's video format unless your application (which I know little about) insists on it.